# Any way to import a saved search file over 10mb to File Cabinet using SuiteScript?

Tags: netsuite

I use SuiteScript to execute Saved Searches and save CSV files to the File Cabinet.  However, the saved files are limited to 10mb or the script fails.  Is there any way to work around the 10mb limit?  I'm able to upload a file through the UI over 10mb in size and the ability to do so using SuiteScript would be very useful.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [@bknights answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53035186/3230114), you can use the `N/task` module to have NetSuite create a CSV for you.

```
var searchTask = task.create({
    taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH
});
searchTask.savedSearchId = 51;
searchTask.filePath = 'ExportFolder/export.csv';;
var searchTaskId = searchTask.submit();
```

If for whatever reason you need more control over the output, you can create files larger than 10MB using `N/file#File.appendLine()` to set the contents of the file line by line.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I now recall reading about this in connection with the 2018.2 release but I totally forgot about it.  No more putting off learning 2.0 for me.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use a SS2.0 N/task method to schedule the script to be published to a file id or path.